# jquery UI datepicker: display the day number only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to display the day number only? (I don't need the full date).

I try: `$('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd'});`
But I still see the full date displayed (e.g. 16-6-13 instead of 16)

there is a way to change it? maybe a kind of known hack...

Answer (score 1):

change the format to dd-mm-yy and try the following on the concerned textbox.

```
$('#textBoXID').change(function(){
    var actualText=$(this).val();
    var arrayOfDate=[];
    arrayOfDate=actualText.split('-');
    $('#textBoXID').val(arrayOfDate[0]); 
});
```

Comment: Nice hack... No "native" way to do it?